# About Printer install with terminal

Tags: printing

You can please tell me the command how can i install printer with terminal.
But i can ask my friends he can tell me we are only install with  printer GUI.

Comment: I would expect you to at least tell us brand and ip it is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the PPD for your printer and install it (the /lpd/ dir is not created by default on Ubuntu; so if it is not yet there create it).

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/lpd/
sudo dpkg --install {printerfile}.deb
```

The command to add a printer is

```
lpadmin
```

But you will need to add a lot of options to this command that are specific to your printer. Help will show you:

```
    lpadmin [-h server] -d destination
    lpadmin [-h server] -x destination
    lpadmin [-h server] -p printer [-c add-class] [-i interface] [-m model]
                       [-r remove-class] [-v device] [-D description]
                       [-P ppd-file] [-o name=value]
                       [-u allow:user,user] [-u deny:user,user]
```

You will need at least a name and an IP. Without any more information about the printer a detailed answer is unlikely.

---

- `lpinfo -m` should show make and model
- shortest version:

  ```
  lpadmin -p '{name}' -v 'socket://{ip}' -m '{make}{model}' -P '{path/to/the/printer.ppd}'
  ```

---

The GUI is a lot easier though. It has several automated settings (like scanning for printers).